# Is "http://.../?var=..." same as "http://.../index.php?var=..."

Tags: php, linux, http, web, lighttpd

Suppose I have a Lighttp server with the default preset and PHP enabled. The server is running on the Linux machine and has only one file (index.php) in the /var/www directory. With that being said, will those two requests:

1. `http://website.com/?var=1`
2. `http://website.com/index.php?var=1`

produce an identical output? Could they be treated as the same request (in this exact case)?

Comment: It depends on the server, if rewrite url is enable it is the same.

Comment: For an `index.php` script, there should be no difference. Without some routing system in place (like in frameworks), when given a URL like `http://website.com/`, `index.php` should be assumed. All that being said, what stops you from trying it?